# Add double quotes to arraylist of string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to stack overflow learning javascript and programming.
 I have a problem that i am stuck while learning and thinking any help on this question will be 
 useful for me thanks and the question is:
 Example i have a variable **a** in the code below and i want to convert it to an array in javascript

`var a = ["baby,cat,dog"]`
i wanted it to be
`a = ["baby","cat","dog"].`

Answer (score 3):

Use [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) as below

```js
var a = ["baby,cat,dog"];
a = a[0].split(',');
console.log(a);
```

Comment: thank you so much for you valuable time it helped me i was thinking like i already have the , in the array and i if use split it won't work thanks but it did work thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You could take the array and map the splitted values and get a flat array back.

```js
var array = ["baby,cat,dog"];
    result = array.flatMap(s => s.split(','));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you so much for you response  i took the answer from @harunur Rashid